# C++ dynamic vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, std-pair

I need to dynamically allocate an array of 5 `vectors` of `pairs`. This code snippet is supposed to add first elements to all 5 `vectors`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> * arr = new std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i].push_back(std::make_pair(i+1, i+11));
}
```

But it adds only 1 element to `arr[0]` vector

```
for (auto el : *arr) {
    std::cout << el.first << ", " << el.second << std::endl;
}
```

Printing out gives `1, 11`
What I need is

```
1, 11
2, 12
3, 13
4, 14
5, 15
```

Please give me some hints. How to work with dynamic vector of pairs?

**EDIT:** Vector of vectors is one possible way. However, I want to use an array of vectors.

Comment: You allocate an array of 5 vectors, not a single vector. Then you add a single element to each of those 5 vectors. Is this what you wanted? Your prose doesn't appear to match your code. You only call `push_back` on `arr[0]` once, so it's unclear why you expect `arr[0].size()` to be anything but 1

Comment: There's *rarely* any need to have pointers to containers. Not even for creation of them.

Comment: the size of an array is only known at runtime

Comment: Your second loop iterates over `arr[0]`, which, again, only contains one element. Did you mean to iterate over all vectors in `arr`? That would be `for (auto v : arr) {  std::cout << (*v)[0].first ...; }`

Comment: Don't you mean that the size of an array must be fixed at *compile-time*? If the size is only known at run-time then use a *vector* (which of course can contain other vectors).

Comment: `for (auto v : arr)` doesn't work

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Won't work very well with pointers.

Comment: You should not be using `new[]`, you should instead use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Side note - consider using `arr[i].emplace_back(i+1, i+11)` instead of `arr[i].push_back(std::make_pair(i+1, i+11))`. Not only it is slightly more readable, it should also be more efficient. Regarding the edit - **why** do you want to use dynamically allocated array of vectors, instead of vector of vectors?

Comment: Because array of vectors is also used for graph representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**:
*Edited entire answer because of the edit of the question.*

---

The statement:

```
for (auto el : *arr) {
    std::cout << el.first << ", " << el.second << std::endl;
}
```

will print the element(s) for the first vector only (i.e. `arr[0]`).
That's because `arr` will decay as a pointer to the first element of the array.

---

If you want to print for all vector**s**, you need to iterate over the size of the **array** (as already done for the insertion):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // arr[i] now is the i-th vector, and you can print whatever you want

    // For example the following will print all element for each vector.
    for (auto el : arr[i]) {
      std::cout << el.first << ", " << el.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my intention is 5 different containers.  So I am missing a point with printing it out. As I said `for (auto el : arr)` doesn't work

Comment: @user2376997 then use *vector of vectors* instead of *dynamically allocated array of vectors*.

Comment: @user2376997 Uhm, I saw only now you've edited the question. I suggest you be more precise in your question. Especially in the usage of *singular/plural*.